# Zend Framework 2 - route parameters after <home> route

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I am trying to solve the routing problem I am facing right now with no luck (googled for hours, saw dozens of examples and solved questions but none works for me - the closest one is this [Routing Zend Framework 2 Language in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691638/routing-zend-framework-2-language-in-url) but even this is not working for me).

I have created an SSO application (I mean the authentication part) and now I am porting it to ZF2 app (I have it almost working as I workarounded the router but need now the final routing to be done) where only these types of URLs are possible:

> http[s]://domain.com/login/asfgsdgdsfgzsdgdsf/
>   http[s]://domain.com/login/tdhjsdgbndfnfgdnhd/
>   http[s]://domain.com/logout/asfgsdgdsfgzsdgdsf/
>   http[s]://domain.com/info/dthnzdfbdfhgnfsd/

Those `login`, `logout` or `info` parts are not the controllers nor actions but the methods names I then call on SSO service from within my `IndexController` and `indexAction()`. The rest part of the URL is the client application hash.

Now here is my router config which only matches the home route and when the other parts (method name [and hash]) are provided, I got 404 from the ZF2 app (so at least I am in the app context).

```php
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type'      => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options'   => array(
                    'route'     => '/',
                    'defaults'  => array(
                        'controller'    => 'SSO\Controller\Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                        'act'           => 'login', // by doing this I am able to workaround the router and work with SSO
                        'client'        => '<my_secret_hash>', // by doing this I am able to workaround the router and work with SSO
                    ),
                ),
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'action' => array(
                        'type'      => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'route'     => '[/:act]',
                            'defaults'  => array(
                                'act' => 'login',
                            ),
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'act' => '(login|logout|info)?', // only login, logout or info are allowed
                            ),
                        ),
                        'child_routes' => array(
                            'client' => array(
                                'type'      => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                                'options'   => array(
                                    'route'     => '[/:client]',
                                    'constraints' => array(
                                        'client'    => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+',
                                    ),
                                    'defaults'  => array(
                                        'client' => '<my_secret_hash>',
                                ),
                                'may_terminate' => true,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

(only `router` part of my *module.config* is provided...)

Now with that router only `http[s]://domain.com[/]` is matched and either of `http[s]://domain.com/(login|logout|info)[/]` or `http[s]://domain.com/(login|logout|info)/adfbsDVdfbzdbxfbndzxbxfnb[/]` matches into **A 404 error occured**.

Though I try to define the route parts as optional (just for the testing and development purposes), they should by required in the production environment. Anyway, I tried to define them NOT optional too, but didn't work either.

Question: **How should I configure the router to match my routes** (URLs) defined in the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things:

- My guess is that you have too many slashes in there -- a child route of `/` doesn't need to be defined with a slash at the beginning since it's parent already got it
- I don't see a reason for 2 nested routes (of course I don't know the rest of your config, so it's a guess)
- `home` route probably should be `Literal` and able to terminate (again a guess)
- there was one unmatched parenthesis (probably 'misspasted' or something)

I suppose this should work for you:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options'   => array(
                'route'     => '/',
                'defaults'  => array(
                    'controller'    => 'SSO\Controller\Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'child_routes' => array(
                'whateva' => array(
                    'type'      => 'Segment',
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'options'   => array(
                        'route'     => '[:act[/:client]]', // as Sam suggested
                        'defaults'  => array(
                            'act' => 'login',
                            'client' => 'fsadfasf32454g43g43543',
                        ),
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'act' => '(login|logout|info)',
                            'client'    => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Good answer, one miss: `[:act[/:client]]` - client parameter should only be present if act-parameter is given. You don't want a client without any action to do, eh ;)

Comment: Great answer, many thanks. I am sure I also tried this one (or something very very similar) but it might happen one line was different and it didn't work... I am curious about this `may_terminate` setting - what does it do exactly? In my app the home (`/`) without `act` and `client` params provided should lead into `404 No action found` and if no `client` param provided into `401 Unauthorized`. So I guess my home (`/`) shouldn't be set to `may_terminate` if I got it right...